# updating a model with respect to a field django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I m doing a bet app and if the admin verify the screenshot sent by the won he will set the verified field to be true .
This is how both the models look like :

```
class ScreenshotVerification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="screenshot")
    user_accepted_bet =models.ForeignKey(AcceptBet,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='screenshotPost')
    user_bet =models.ForeignKey(CreateBet,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='screenshotBet')
    screenshot_img = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media/screenshot',blank = True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=None)
```

```
class Won(models.Model):
    won_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="won_user")
    loss_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="loss_user")
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

so whenever verified field set to true I want the value of `won_user` and `loss_user` to be automatically be created.
Thanq in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `ScreenshotVerification` object already exists, I think it would be something like the following (I don't know the logic of your app so this is a best guess).

```py
class ScreenshotVerification(models.Model):
    ...
    @transaction.atomic
    def verify_win(self):
        self.verified = True
        self.save()
        Won.objects.create(won_user=self.user)
```

If the `ScreenshotVerification` object does not exist, then create a custom method on a [Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers), and call with:

```
ScreenshotVerification.objects.verify_win(user)
```

[This article](https://www.dabapps.com/blog/django-models-and-encapsulation/) explains this approach.

Note also that the use of the `atomic` decorator is very important.

Comment: that idea seems to be great  but I wonder why it is not updating the ```won``` model . When I checked the ```won``` model it is still appeared to be empty .@Matthew Hegarty

Comment: here in my case the `ScreenshotVerification` object already exists . The user will sent the  screenshot. all the admin have to do is set the status to true .